# Como imprimir cifras completas en un dataframe que no aparezca el "+"

Tags: python, dataframe

Alguien por favor me podría informar lo que debo hacer para que al imprimir  un dataframe se puedan ver las cifras completas sin el "+", por ejemplo el número `2.166200e+09` que se vea completo.

Traté de cambiar el tipo de datos a `int` con:

```
 astype(int)
```

Pero sale igual.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido, es demasiado importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste por favor, revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: Listo editado. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

encontré esta opción para solucionar mi pregunta, esto evita que salgan los números en notación científica.

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.2f}'.format
```

Comment: Cabe recalcar que también te redondea el número a 2 decimales.

Answer (score 0):

Me pasaba cuando importaba un excell que tenia datos en decimal del tipo : **2000056,36 me los mostraba en notacion cientifica 2.0000e+09** y no lograba hacerlo. Al usar el código que pones

> `pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.2f}'.format`

modifica la forma en que pandas muestra por defecto los datos del tipo Float que es en notacion cientifica y los nuestra de la forma en que estamos acostumbrados a verlos nosotros, es decir en Base 10.